# Custom filter undefined throwing error when clicking on it ag-grid

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid

I'm trying to use custom filter from the example here https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-provided-simple/#filterOptions and when I click on it it shows error: [image]
It's not even a date filter, why does it fail? In the filter tab it also doesn't show the title and says undefined, does the example not work anymore?

```js
 this.columnDefs.push({
                colId: i + 1,
                field: `${i + 1}`,
                headerName: header,
                filter: 'agNumberColumnFilter',
                filterParams: {
                    filterOptions: ['inRange', 'equals', 'notEqual', 'lessThan', 'greaterThan', 'lessThanOrEqual', 'greaterThanOrEqual',
                        {
                            displayKey: 'lessThanWithNulls',
                            displayName: 'Less Than with Nulls',
                            test: function (filterValue, cellValue) {
                                return cellValue == null || cellValue < filterValue;
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                menuTabs: ['filterMenuTab'],
                valueFormatter: (params: any) => {
                    if (!params || !params.data || !params.data.values)
                        return '';
                    let val = '';
                    if (params.node.rowIndex === params.data.rowId) {
                        const data = params.data.values.find(x => x.colId === params.colDef.colId);

                        val = this.formatValue(data);
                    }
                    params.value = val;
                    return params.value ? params.value : '';
                },
                valueGetter: (params: any) => {
                    if (!params || !params.data || !params.data.values)
                        return '';
                    let val = '';
                    if (params.node.rowIndex === params.data.rowId) {
                        const data = params.data.values.find(x => x.colId === params.colDef.colId);

                        val = this.formatValue(data);
                        val = val ? val.substr(0, val.indexOf(' ')).replace(',', '.') : '';
                    }
                    // use formatted value as number for filtering
                    params.value = +val;
                    return params.value;
                },
            );
```

```html
<ag-grid #grid class="ag-fresh" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" [enableColResize]="enableColResize"
    [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents" [height]="height" [enableFilter]="true" [localeText]="localeText"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs" [autoSizeColumns]="autoSizeColumns" (cellDoubleClicked)="cellDoubleClicked($event)"
    [enableSorting]="enableSorting" [rowSelection]="rowSelection" (selectionChanged)="selectionChanged()"
    [rowData]="model">
</ag-grid>
```

Comment: I'm having this exact issue, did you find anything useful? Looking at the source code of ag-grid where it is failing, i can't quite see how it can support custom options

Comment: This is because the version I have installed (and the version I have a licence for) is an older version. If you upgrade to latest my guess is that it will work for you - the documentation is for the latest version not necessarily the version you have installed

Comment: @user122222 did you find any solution for this?